# Expose expiring URL with compressed file

Tags: amazon-s3

The ***requirement*** is:

1. A **technical user** creates a DB backup from postgreSQL (pg_dump)
2. The **technical user**  uploads the file to a bucket in the closes AWS region
3. the **technical** user gets an URL that should expire every week
4. **technical user** user sends the URL to 2-4 people with little IT knowledge: the **non-technical user**
5. **non-technical user**  downloads the file accessing the temporary URL and replace it into a Docker Container Bind Volume local location

***Constrains:***

1. AWS **technical user** doesn't have permissions to generate AIM access key nor secret key
2. AWS S3 must be used as the organization uses AWS and strategically the purpose will be to have everything centralized in AWS infrastructure

I am following this documentation about [presigned object URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html)

- **What do you suggest?**

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to create Iam user and consume the credentials with an small application (server side). There is Api already created by aws to connect any programming language. Personally I use symfony you have bundles to connect to s3 directly. Under my perspective I recommending you to create a simple interface to upload the backup and provide access to people with roles according to your necessities.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I would have to into detail about symphony. I would like to create a simple interface although i dont know if the effort is too high. 
We opted to just simply put the file in GitLab for the moment..l

Comment: Hi Andres. I think you will be spending two working days to reach your goal. You can use bundles already created like fosuserbundle for authentication. To upload files you have nice things like Dropzone library. I recommend you upload the file with a presigned url (that url is created from programming language)